# Execute loops in multiple nodes at the same time?

Tags: ros, node, threads, multi-thread

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a system that has two ROS nodes, each with a while loop that waits for a certain amount of time to pass. However, when the first node enters its loop, the rest of the system freezes waiting for the loop to complete.

The question: Is there a way to execute my ROS system so that several nodes can run at the same time, even with loops running within? Perhaps the solution lies with threading or parallelism?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12924/execute-loops-in-multiple-nodes-at-the-same-time?/) by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 353 on 2012-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2012-02-07**:
What is "the rest of the system"? Is the node that's locking up expected to execute any callbacks while it's waiting? Why not use one of the system sleep functions instead of a while loop?

**Comment by [gavinmachine](https://answers.ros.org/users/1039/gavinmachine/) on 2012-02-07**:
The only thing I've thought of is to use the ros::Rate loop_rate to slow the loops down. This seems to work, but I'm not sure if it's an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each ROS node is a single process (see first sentence in the [Nodes documentation](http://ros.org/wiki/Nodes)), so what you describe should not happen. Have you actually tried what you describe or is it just a description of what you assume would happen? Being two separate processes, two nodes already run in parallel and one will not block the other (apart from some special cases on could probably construct somehow).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1